# Multiplying values from different tables

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables in my database. The first one is Staff, which contains all staff members and ther hourly wage.

```
staffid     staffname   wage
-----------------------------
1           Joe         15
2           Bill        14
```

Then there's Hours, which contains the amount of hours each Staff has worked.

```
staffid     date         hours
------------------------------
1           03.02.2014   8
2           03.02.2014   6
```

Now what I want to do is to display the amount of money the Staff made each day.
So the output could look something like this:

```
staffid     date        amount
------------------------------
1           03.02.2014  120
2           03.02.2014  84
```

How would I do this with SQL? Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible for someone to have two records on the same day?  (For instance, if s/he worked two different shifts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select s.staffid, 
       h.date, 
       h.hours * s.wage as amount
from staff s
inner join hours h on h.staffid = s.staffid
```